# Roblox Lua Script, How to make a frame decrease its size from left to right?

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a health bar that decreases from left to right instead of from right to left
and it has to be this way because of how the interface looks, I've tried different calculations but all of them were close but too far and I'm running out of ideas on how to make it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look into [anchor point](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/GuiObject/AnchorPoint).

What anchor point does is set the origin of the UI. So for your use case, you'll probably want to set the anchor point to [`1,0`]. Which means the UI will scale to the left

---

(White Box) Anchor point 0,0
[image: Anchor Point 0,0]

(White Box) Anchor point 1,0
[image: Anchor Point 1,0]

With an anchor point of 1,0, it will scale to the left

---

Comment: it may help me but i'm trying to use player's health to resize the frame from left to right

Comment: Try setting the frame's anchor point to 1,0. You'll notice that it will flip. Then you should be able to adjust it from there @oreto (Added image examples to the post)